# Display datepicker in clone rows

Tags: jquery

I have an datepicker like this:

```
<input name="eventDate" type="text" id="eventDate" size="12" class="textbox">
```

To show the calendar, I use this statement:

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[ 
var opts = { formElements:{"eventDate":"d-sl-m-sl-Y"} };     
datePickerController.createDatePicker(opts);
// ]]>  
</script>
```

My problem is I want to create a form that every time the user presses the button "Add Row", a new row is as above will appear and all datepicker named "eventDate" in each row should work. How can I do that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you post the whole code so I can understand it whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the cloned input field to the datepicker so basicly just reset the datepickers after inserting the new row.

Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/466C8/

```
$('.addRow').click( function() {
    $('.cont').append('<input name="eventDate" type="text" class="eventDate" size="12" class="textbox" /><br />');
    $( ".eventDate" ).datepicker();
});
```

And you should use classes if you're going to clone these elements. It won't work with IDs if they're all the same.
There's also pretty great amount of this question with good answers in SO, try the search.